How to enable SAML as authentication provider in MS Entra?
I've build a web application which should support SSO, so the users can login to my app using their company account. The company uses MS Active Directory and I the company requires to use SAML2.
For testing purposes I create my own applicaiton in the MS Entra Admin planel. I followed this tutorial https://knowledgebase.businessmap.io/hc/en-us/articles/115004167265-How-to-Set-Up-SAML-Single-Sign-%D0%9En-with-Microsoft-Entra-ID but when I choose my app under "enterprise accplications" I don't see the SAML button.

I'm not sure if SAML should work out of the box. When I try to login using SAML, the endpoint seems to be active but I got the following message:
AADSTS7500511: XML attribute 'AssertionConsumerServiceURL' in the SAML message must be a URI. I googled and some answers refering to a missing value in the SAML config in the admin panel.

Did you create the application in App registeration blade or Enterprise app blade

@Rukmini Thanks for your answer! I will check and reply tomorrow morning.

Works fine now thanks! So the way I created the application was wrong before.

Glad to know that it worked:)

I created a Microsoft Entra ID application in the App registration blade and in the Enterprise application there was no SAML option to enable:
Got the same issue


Note that: Selecting Register an application to integrate with Azure AD (App you're developing) option integrates with Azure AD and allows to use OIDC standard for SSO.


And the application created in App registration blade also use OIDC standard for SSO.

To enable SAML single sign on, you need to create application in Enterprise application blade:
Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Applications -> Create your own application -> Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery (Non-gallery) -> Create


And you can also see this application in App registration blade:

Make sure the user is added in the users and groups blade of the application:

Configure the values and test the application:

Reference:
Allow to select SAML sign-on method for existing Azure enterprise application - Stack Overflow by me
